# Swift 4: Problem with centerXAnchor and centerYAnchor Auto Constraints not centering UIView in center of view

Tags: uiscrollview, swift4, centering

I am having problems getting a UIView that I created to be anchored in the center of one of my view controller. I think there could be two possible reasons why my view isn't being centered correctly:

1. My code for centering the UIView in the view controller using centerXAnchor and centerYAnchor is wrong
2. Since the view controller that I am adding the UIView to is one of three view controllers in a scroll view that swipes left and right, the compiler might think that the centerXAnchor and centerYAnchor are in the middle of the two view controllers that are off screen when the app starts up.  I am adding the UIView to the second view controller which is the first one that is off screen.

Any help solving this problem would be much appreciated!

Screenshot of second view controller in scroll view:

[image]

Code for second view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class SecondHomeScrollVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        setupGraphDisplay()
    }

    func setupGraphDisplay() {
        let trackerGraph = TrackerGraphView()
        trackerGraph.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        trackerGraph.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(trackerGraph)
        trackerGraph.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        trackerGraph.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        trackerGraph.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        trackerGraph.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are not searchable, nor are they accessible. It is better to [edit] the question and paste in the code and use the code format button, or indent the code manually with four spaces.

Comment: Just pasted code:)

Comment: *"I am adding the UIView to the second view controller which is the first one that is off screen."* -- sounds like the view you're adding this view to is not constrained correctly. You may find it helpful to use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect all of your views.